# What's the first movie or TV episode portraying a computer password?

Tags: first-appearance

Scenes of computer hackers trying to crack someone's password are very common today, but when you think about those scenes only work because the audience are aware that computers are secured using passwords, and securing computers with a password is a rather new thing when compared with the history of cinema. So the question becomes, which movie (or TV episode) was the first to portray a computer system secured using a password (documentaries don't count)?

Comment: One of these, probably; http://www.starringthecomputer.com/features.html. Maybe Wargames - 1983?

Answer (score 2):

The first I found in Subzin is from [*WarGames* (1983)](http://www.subzin.com/quotes/M9143247f/WarGames/They+change+the+password+every+couple+of+weeks%2C+but+I+know+where+they+write+it.). Here's the first mention:

> 00:19:52 - You're really into computers, huh? - Yeah.
>
> 00:19:59 - What are you doing? - I'm dialing into the school's computer.
>
> 00:20:14 They change the **password** every couple of weeks, but I know where they write it.
>
> 00:20:32 - Are those your grades?! - Yeah.
>
> 00:20:35 I don't think that I deserved an F, do you?

Here's a screenshot:

[image: the password is pencil]

Others:

> 00:25:35 They might have changed the **password**.
>
> 00:32:15 I put in a **password** that only I know about.
>
> 00:35:32 so I could get his secret **password**.
>
> 00:36:18 If I could just get that damn **password**, I could play the computer.
>
> 00:52:28 The kid broke into the war game using a **password** left by the original programmer.
>
> 00:52:33 - A **password**? - Yes, sir.
>
> 00:52:43 We can find the **password** and take it out, but it might help to beef up security.
>
> 01:36:08 It's like the entire **password** file has been wiped out.
>
> 01:38:15 They've taken out my **password**.

Answer (score 2):

I remember an episode of a detective series Simon and Simon about a boy who was hacking bank accounts on a bank system.

According to Google the episode is Trapdoors from 1981, script is here:

[Simon and Simon S01E03 Trapdoors](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=simon-and-simon-1981&episode=s01e03)

There is mention of passwords as part of trying to access systems.